# Applying PHP MYSQLI Select to Bootstrap grid system

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, select, grid

Im trying to implement bootstrap grid system using php and below is the result that I want.

**desired result**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsguz.jpg

but 
I got this result https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n8oZ.png with the php code below. I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

<?
$sql = "SELECT id, title, article, date, file FROM article";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<div class='col-sm-2'>

    <img src='article/image/".$row["file"]."' class='img-responsive' width='100%' height='100%'></img></a>
    <h4><strong> ". $row["title"]. "</strong></h4>
    <h5>
    ";
    custom_echo ($row['content'],200);
    echo "</h5><a href='/image/". $row["title"]. "'></h5><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Read More</a></di>";
     }
}else{
     echo "<div class='col-sm-8'>No article</div>";    
}

$conn->close();
?>
       </div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
```

can someone point me the right way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

There you go! I'd consider going through some basic HTML tutorials.

```
<div class="row">
    <?
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, article, date, file FROM article";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<div class='col-sm-2'>
                        <img src='article/image/".$row["file"]."' class='img-responsive' width='100%' height='100%'></img>
                        <h4><strong> ". $row["title"]. "</strong></h4>
                        <h5>";

                        custom_echo($row['content'], 200);

            echo "      </h5>
                        <a href='http://link.to.article/' class='btn btn-success'>Read More</a>
                  </div>";


         }
    }else{
         echo "<div class='col-sm-8'>No article</div>";    
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>
```